# Python equivalent of Excel's Cubic interpolation

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolation

In Excel there is a function called `Cubicinterpolation()`. I am looking for an equivalent function in Python which should be able to closely match the results.

Is there any such function/method available with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scipy` package and [`interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) function:

```
# pip install scipy
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)
f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')
```

Usage:

```
>>> f(1.5)
array(0.60644424)

>>> f([2.5, 4.5])
array([0.4346027 , 0.22312461])
```